# How do I rename lots of files on a directory without changing their extensions?

Tags: shell, scripting, rename

I have a problem! I have a bunch of image files with extensions. Jpg and. Png. I wrote a script that renames the files, changing their names in a pattern followed by a number like this:

...
arquivo_1.jpg
arquivo_2.jpg
...
  And following this sequence, but it needs to know the extension, in this case I used the extension. Jpg.

I was wondering how do I optimize the script so that it renames but keeping the original extension of the file and keep doing the sequence I described above. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have a filename in a variable: `file=photo.jpg`

You can get the extension like this: `ext=${file##*.}`

That removes, from the beginning of the string, all character up to and including the *last* dot:

```
$ echo $ext
jpg
```

See
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion